# is it possible to find a matching bracket in chrome developer tool in source javascript files in mac

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

I am looking for a shortcut to find a matching bracket in Chrome developer tool in mac.

The shortcut to do this in Windows machine is <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>.

If we see full list of shortcuts in [google developer site](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/shortcuts?utm_source=devtools),

The shortcut is <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>m</kbd>

But in my mac machine, the all it does is minimize the screen.

Comment: Devtools allows customizing the shortcuts now. Open devtools -> settings -> experiments -> enable keyboard shortcut editor. Reopen devtools -> settings -> shortcuts.

Comment: @wOxxOm In my chrome installation, enable keyboard shortcut editor is not available. I can attach the screenshot.

Comment: @wOxxOm even when the experimental feature is enabled to edit the shortcut, but in the shortcut tab there is no option to edit the matching bracket shortcut.

Comment: You can report it on https://crbug.com.